# Como fazer este tipo de select no banco de dados Firebase Cloud Firestore?

Tags: android-studio, firebase, flutter, dart

como eu faço esse tipo de `select` no banco de dados Firebase Cloud Firestore ?

```
 _results = (await connection.query('select id from produtos where numero_serie = $_numeroSerie'))
```

> Eu preciso pegar o id do produto que esta no banco de dados firebase onde a coluna
> numero_serie tenha o mesmo valor da variável  _numeroSerie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isto deu certo e não repete a mesma variável no banco

```
final QuerySnapshot result = await Future.value(Firestore.instance
    .collection("lockers")
    .where("numero_serie", isEqualTo: "$_numeroSerie")
    .limit(1)
    .getDocuments());

final List<DocumentSnapshot> documents = result.documents;
if (documents.length == 1) {
  confirmacao(context);
} else {
  await Firestore.instance
      .collection("lockers")
      .document()
      .setData({"numero_serie": _numeroSerie});
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

// Cria referencia para a collection produtos

`var produtosRef = db.collection("produtos");`

// Cria a consulta

`var query = produtosRef.where("numero_serie", "==", $_numeroSerie)`

Consulte a documentação oficial do Firebase em português [aqui](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries).